# What is the cost function in cv.glm in R's boot package?

Tags: r, cross-validation

I'm doing a cross validation using the leave-one-out method. I have a binary response and am using the boot package for R, and the [cv.glm function](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/boot/html/cv.glm.html). My problem is that I don't fully understand the "cost" part in this function. From what I can understand this is the function that decides whether an estimated value should be classified as a 1 or a 0, i.e the threshold value for the classification. Is this correct?

And, in the help in R they use this function for a binomial model: `cost <- function(r, pi = 0) mean(abs(r-pi) > 0.5)`. How do I interpret this function? so I can modify it correctly for my analysis.

Any help is appreciated, don't want to use a function I don't understand.

Answer (score 9):

r is a vector that contains the actual outcome, pi is a vector that contains the fitted values.

```
cost <- function(r, pi = 0) mean(abs(r-pi) > 0.5)
```

This is saying $cost = \sum|r_i - pi_i|$. You can define your own cost functions. In your case for binary classification you can do something like this

```
mycost <- function(r, pi){
    weight1 = 1 #cost for getting 1 wrong
    weight0 = 1 #cost for getting 0 wrong
    c1 = (r==1)&(pi<0.5) #logical vector - true if actual 1 but predict 0
    c0 = (r==0)&(pi>=0.5) #logical vector - true if actual 0 but predict 1
    return(mean(weight1*c1+weight0*c0))
  }
```

and put mycost as an argument in the cv.glm function.

Comment: Shouldn't $cost$ be something like $$\sum \Bigl\lfloor \frac{|r_i-p_i|}{0.5}\Bigr\rfloor$$ (with the exception, when $|r_i-p_i|=1$, then the term is $1$, not $2$)?

Comment: @feng-mai pi==0 or pi < 0.5? ( and pi==1 or pi > 0.5?) if using 0.5 as the decision boundary. Are not the pi the predicted *probabilities*?

Comment: @PM Yes you are right. $pi$ are the responses from the glm model. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

```
cost <- function(r, pi = 0) mean(abs(r-pi) > 0.5)
```

First, you have set a cut-off as 0.5. Your r is 0/1, but pi is probability. So individual cost is 1 if absolute error is greater than 0.5, otherwise 0.
Then, this function calculates the average error rate.
But remember, the cut-off has been set before you define your cost function.

Actually, I think it makes more sense if the choice of cut-off is determined by cost function.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @SLi already explains very well what the cost function you have defined does. However, I thought I would add that the cost function is used to calculate the `delta` value from `cv.glm`, which is a measurement of the cross validation error. However, critically `delta` is the weighted average of the error of each fold given by the cost. We see this by inspecting the relevant bit of the code:

```
for (i in seq_len(ms)) {
    j.out <- seq_len(n)[(s == i)]
    j.in <- seq_len(n)[(s != i)]
    Call$data <- data[j.in, , drop = FALSE]
    d.glm <- eval.parent(Call)
    p.alpha <- n.s[i]/n # create weighting for averaging later
    cost.i <- cost(glm.y[j.out], predict(d.glm, data[j.out, 
        , drop = FALSE], type = "response"))
    CV <- CV + p.alpha * cost.i # add previous error to running total
    cost.0 <- cost.0 - p.alpha * cost(glm.y, predict(d.glm, 
        data, type = "response"))
}
```

and the value returned by the function is:

```
  list(call = call, K = K, delta = as.numeric(c(CV, CV + cost.0)), 
    seed = seed)
```