# Cost function in cv. glm for a fitted logistic model when cutoff value of the model is not 0.5

Tags: r, logistic, cross-validation

I have a logistic model fitted with the following R function:

```
glmfit<-glm(formula, data, family=binomial)
```

A  reasonable cutoff value in order to get a good data classification (or confusion matrix) with the fitted model is 0.2 instead of the mostly used 0.5.

And I want to use the `cv.glm` function with the fitted model:

```
cv.glm(data, glmfit, cost, K)
```

Since the response in the fitted model is a binary variable an appropriate cost function is (obtained from "Examples" section of ?cv.glm):

```
cost <- function(r, pi = 0) mean(abs(r-pi) > 0.5)
```

As I have a cutoff value of 0.2, can I apply this standard cost function or should I define a different one and how?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: "A reasonable cutoff value in order to get a good data classification (or confusion matrix) with the fitted model is 0.2 instead of the mostly used 0.5." Just curious, but how do you know that 0.2 is a better cutoff than 0.5?

Comment: I very much recommend our earlier thread [Classification probability threshold](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312119/1352).

Answer (score 1):

OK, No answers to my post. But I think I got the answer. All credits go to @Feng Mai. He wrote a post here: [What is the cost function in cv.glm in R's boot package?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45569/what-is-the-cost-function-in-cv-glm-in-rs-boot-package?rq=1) and thanks to it here is my answer to my question:

For a cutoff value of 0.2, I think that I could I apply the following cost function:

```
 mycost <- function(r, pi){
 weight1 = 1 #cost for getting 1 wrong
 weight0 = 1 #cost for getting 0 wrong
 c1 = (r==1)&(pi<0.2) #logical vector - true if actual 1 but predict 0
 c0 = (r==0)&(pi>0.2) #logical vecotr - true if actual 0 but predict 1
 return(mean(weight1*c1+weight0*c0))
 }
```

And then I would use the `cv.glm` function with the fitted model and mycost function:

```
cv.glm(data, glmfit, cost=mycost, K)
```

Hopefully this might work. Am I right?

Comment: I think that it is not proper to do this unless the cost function has been specified from subject matter experts.  It is not a statistical quantity, and often varies with subjects.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

```
cost <- function(r, pi = 0) mean(abs(r-pi) > 0.2)
```

The logic follows:

1. If your cutoff is 0.2, then predict an outcome of `1` if `pi` is greater than 0.2.
2. Therefore, the number of times you are wrong is given by summing the logical vector

   ```
   abs(r-pi) > 0.2
   ```

   We can arrive at this by looking at both cases where the prediction is wrong:

   ```
   if r = 0 and pi > 0.2
   if r = 1 and pi <= 0.2
   ```

   In both cases,  `abs(r - pi) > 0.2` will return the value `TRUE`, meaning that the prediction is wrong.

Comment: The cutoff comes from the cost function, not vice versa.  And the only way a cutoff exists is for the cost function to be identical across all units.